# how to copy values in a diagonal down a range using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data in one column like so:

[image]

and I'm trying to copy each value after the one in "A1" and move it one column over and up one row, for example (A2 copied to B1, A3 copied to B2, A4 copied to B3 etc.) like so:

[image]

Is there a few lines of code that can do this successfully?

Comment: So the end result is supposed to be one row with all values from left to right? Or a triangle, with each column having one less data entry than the column to the left?

Comment: Yes, it's a simple 1-2 liner, but this isn't a code writing service.  Please put in some effort on your end, and show your code if you still can't figure it out.  You can at least start by recording a macro and then going from there.

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Answer (score 2):

In B1:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(OFFSET($A1,COLUMN()-1,0)),"",OFFSET($A1,COLUMN()-1,0))
```

fill down and across

Answer (score 1):

Alternate:

```
=IF(ROW(B1)>COUNTA($A:$A)-COLUMN(A1),"",INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(B1)+ROW(B1)-1))
```